# feGaussianBlur, feOffset and other SVG tags not working in Pyside WebView

Tags: svg, pyside, svg-filters, svg-animate

Does PySide WebView not support these tags? Or is there anyway to  support these tags?

This is my SVG Code. I have made an SVG circle which takes this filter and **performs some color transition using javascript**

```
     <defs>
        <filter id="blurr">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1" />
            <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" />
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
```

In PySide, I have made a simple WebView which displays this HTML file.

The HTML file shows the color transition properly in browser but in PySide, It doesn't show any color change.

Comment: Here's another, more informative, bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9081?page=com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities%3atransitions-summary-tabpanel), filters are not supported and it seems the project has no plans to do so given that the bug has been closed.